# How to see whether a tori is an abelian variety or not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Given an explicit lattice $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, how can one check whether the complex torus $\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$ is a projective or not?

Comment: [Riemann's bilinear relations](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/riemanns-bilinear-relations/)